# Get unique elements (elements that don't repeat next to each other) from a sequence

Tags: python, list, function, for-loop, indexing

I am trying to write a func() that returns only unique elements from a given input, in the same order.

for  e.g - 'AAAABBBCCDAABBB' will return ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B']

Just a beginner therefore it would great if i can get some help.
Attached my code below - apologies if it is not best practice in terms of readability.

```
enter code here 
def unique_in_order(string):

new_list =[]


#using a for loop access the elements 
for n in range(len(string)):
    
    print(string[n],string[n+1])
    
    if string[n] != string[n+1]:
        new_list.append(string[n])
        
return new_list
```

The output i get
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When checking last element of the string you are accessing the element *n+1* that is out of string's bounds. Corrected code looks like this:

```
def unique_in_order(string):
    if len(string) == 0:
        return [];
    new_list = [string[0]]
    #using a for loop access the elements 
    for n in range(1, len(string)):        
        print(string[n-1],string[n])
        if string[n] != string[n-1]:
            new_list.append(string[n])
    return new_list
```

Answer (score 0):

In python you can use groupby method to do this

```
from itertools import groupby

my_str = "AAAABBBCCDAABBB"
res = list(map(lambda x: x[0], groupby(my_str)))

print(res) # ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B']
```

Answer (score 0):

You are facing index error in the last loop. Since you are checking `string[n+1]`
In the last loop when you do n+1 it will be out of index.

Comment: Yes i understood the error but just didnt attempt to do n-1 ! Thanks once again

Answer (score 0):

This could be one way of doing it. This looks to the item before rather than the item ahead, so you won't get the error you're getting.

```
def unique_in_order(string):
    new_list = []
    for i in range(len(string)):
        # if the new letter isn't same as previous then add to list
        if string[i] != string[i - 1]: 
             new_list.append(string[i])
        else:
             pass
    return new_list `
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex?

```
>>> re.findall(r'(.)\1*', 'AAAABBBCCDAABBB')
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B']
```